# Requiring two dependencies in angular directive

Tags: angularjs

One can use the require property to add a dependency to a custom directive, for instance

> require: '^?form'

Is it possible to add more than one dependency?

I'm writing a directive, which needs to have the ngFormController as well as the ngModelController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use an array:

```
require: [
  '^?form',
  '^otherDirective'
]
```

And on the `link` function you will receive an array of controllers instead of only 1 controller:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
  // controllers[0] == formController
  // controllers[1] == otherDirectiveController 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see here [Official doc for $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) - it covers directives very well.

```
require: 'siblingDirectiveName', // or // ['^parentDirectiveName', '?optionalDirectiveName', '?^optionalParent'],
```

If you pass an array to require, the fourth argument to your `link` function will be an array of controllers in the order specified with require.